# Trouble linking Tim Bolstad's Core Audio Example

Tags: core-audio

I'm probably missing something simple, but I'm getting the following linker error when trying to build:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "CAStreamBasicDescription::CAStreamBasicDescription()", referenced from:
          -[AudioController initializeAUGraph] in AudioController.o
          -[AudioController .cxx_construct] in AudioController.o
      "CAStreamBasicDescription::AsString(char*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
          CAStreamBasicDescription::PrintFormat(__sFILE*, char const*, char const*) const in AudioController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can't figure out what's going on here as the compiler is finding CAStreamBasicDescription.h just fine.  I've seen suggestions of clearing the framework search path when encountering this type of error, but there's nothing in that path. Probably something simple, but I feel like I'm drinking from a fire hose.  Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to call this a solution, I was able to work around this and get Tim's example to compile by modifying it to use `AudioStreamBasicDescription` instead of `CAStreamBasicDescription`. Aside from a couple one-line changes you just need to duplicate the functionality of `SetAUCanonical`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added `CAStreamBasicDescription.cpp` to your project also? It's part of the unofficial Core Audio SDK, so it isn't available unless you compile it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried replacing CAStreamBasicDescription.h with CAStreamBasicDescription.cpp (which immediately #includes CAStreamBasicDescription.h). Now the error is: ld: duplicate symbol CAStringForOSType(unsigned long, char*) etc. Ideas?

Comment: Can you create a sample project illustrating the problem? There are too many sources of compiler errors to narrow down without more data.

Comment: A year later, I am having the same exact problem (well, my error is missing the part about `CAStreamBasicDescription` but the `AsString` bit is identical), and `CAStreamBasicDescription.cpp` is definitely included in my project. Sample project if you're still willing to take a look: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14083292/iPhoneAudio.zip

Comment: @yuji In addition to adding the `.cpp` files to your project you also need to add them to your target so they will be compiled.  I did this and your project built successfully.