# Using custom cocoapod gives compile errors (Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I built my own pod for my own internal usage. The pod spec lint worked fine but when I tried to actually use it, it gave me the following compile errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___gxx_personality_sj0", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for CAXException in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "std::__throw_bad_alloc()", referenced from:
      std::_Vector_base<AudioBufferList*, std::allocator<AudioBufferList*> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "CAStreamBasicDescription::CAStreamBasicDescription()", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
      std::_Vector_base<AudioBufferList*, std::allocator<AudioBufferList*> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<AudioBufferList*, std::allocator<AudioBufferList*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<AudioBufferList**, std::vector<AudioBufferList*, std::allocator<AudioBufferList*> > >, AudioBufferList* const&) in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMusicPlayerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libPods.a(AudioManager.o)
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      _GetConvertedData in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
      std::vector<AudioBufferList*, std::allocator<AudioBufferList*> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<AudioBufferList**, std::vector<AudioBufferList*, std::allocator<AudioBufferList*> > >, AudioBufferList* const&) in libPods.a(ExtAudioFileConvert.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I suspect the frameworks are not set properly in the podspec as this is my first pod to write and I probably have a few mistakes in there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link against: 1. the C++ standard library, 2. the Core Audio framework, 3. the MediaPlayer framework.

Comment: I added MediaPlayer and CoreAudio. This reduced 18 errors to 17.
Not sure how to link the C++ standard library though. Looked online and found the following but it didn't help:
   s.xcconfig = { 'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY' => 'libstdc++' }

Comment: perhaps compile as C++ instead of C. `-lstdc++` should do the job on the command line; I don't use Xcode so I don't know how you can make it tell the linker to link against libstdc++.

Comment: Thanks H2CO3. Your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially answering the question I posted. I needed to do the following to fix it:

- Link the C++ standard library: (Thanks to @H2CO3)

  - add `s.library    = 'stdc++'` to the **podspec**
- Link MediaPlayer framework: (Thanks to @H2CO3)

  - add `s.frameworks = 'MediaPlayer'` to the **podspec**
- Issue with **CAStreamBasicDescription** was fixed by following the answer of: [Trouble linking Tim Bolstad's Core Audio Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780928/trouble-linking-tim-bolstads-core-audio-example)